# Rewrite old post images to https

Tags: nginx, ssl

I moved my site from http to https. I changed all template content to ssl, but the images in old posts are still served with http.

How to catch all images and rewrite them to ssl with Nginx?

Comment: Internal links in Wordpress (including to images) *should* be relative to the install URL. Did you set it correctly? (`Settings->General: Wordpress URL / Site URL`).

Comment: For the template they are all relative now. But for the 'media' urls in posts they are not.

Comment: This appears to be a problem you should fix on the Wordpress level. Migrating to [wordpress.se]

Answer (score -1):

It's very primitive method but works in any case;

- Make a dump from MySQL
- Open it with text editor or maybe another tool you liked (If your dump is so big, you'll need a strong computer.)
- Find all `http://example.com`, replace with `https://example.com` and save.
- Rename/move the old database for backup, import the edited database.
- Leave the cave and go hunting.

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit a raw dump of a database; a text find/replace will break serialized data in the database, i.e. break widget data, theme options, etc. Use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases